# Connect to Informix database using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-connection, informix, squirrel-sql

I want to connect to informix database from Visual Studio 2013. I've checked the IBM site and it contains whole lot of drivers and plugins. I've installed Client SDK and then I installed IBM server driver package then I installed Visual Studio add-in.

- I tried connecting using setnet 32 and I'm able to succeed.
- I'm able to connect to database using Squirrel and IBM Data Studio.
- I'm able to connect to server using Visual Studio but **it crashes when I opened a new query**.

How can I connect to an Informix database from Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Which version of CSDK did you install?  Which Windows O/S are you using — Windows 7, 8, 8.1, something else?  You say "it crashes"; which "it" — VS itself, or the program you're developing, or …?

Comment: Client SDK Version - clientsdk.3.70.TC7DE.WIN, OS - Win 8.1, I tried just to add a new informix database server in Visual Studio. I'm able to add it using ODBC connection. But Visual Studio itself crashes when I opened a new query.

Comment: CSDK 3.70 was probably released before Windows 8.1 (though TC7 indicates it is a later fix pack release, so maybe things changed).  Are you sure that version is certified for use on Windows 8.1?  Should you be using 4.10 instead?  I'm surprised that VS itself crashes.  I also know I have no idea about what's going on.  Is VS trying to run the query for you, rather than making you write a program to run the query?  Have you found a cause for the crash, such as dereferencing a null pointer, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon. I'll uninstall the CSDK 3.70 and I'll give a try with 4.10. For more clarity, I'm not writing any program to run a query. I just want to use Visual Studio as an IDE for running queries and creating new fucntion and SP's like Squirrel.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify how are you trying to connect IDS database.
Are you trying to connect the database by using application code such as ODBC, .NET, ESQL/C etc while it is debug using VS.

Or

are you trying to create a connection node under VS database explorer.
If it is VS database explorer then Informix CSDK do not have support for it. 
You will have to install IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio 2013.
This Add-Ins are part of IBM Data Server driver package. 
This connectivity uses DRDA protocol, so you will have to enable DRDA port on the IDS server. 
Then try create VS database explorer entries by specifying the DRDA port.
(or connect if the entry already exist)

Comment: I'm not building any applications for informix database.I'm just trying to create connection under VS database explorer. I've installed installed the IBM database Add-Ins for Visual Studio 2013 ( Version - ibm_database_addins_for_visualstudio_v10.5). I also installed ibm_data_server_runtime_client_win64_v10.5.

Comment: You may first verify the connection to the database works fine or not.
It can be tested by using the tool testconn40.exe.
You may specify connection string as argument to this tool. 
It is located at SQLLIB\BIN\testconn40.exe

Once the connectivity is working then try creating DB explorer entry with VS.

Comment: Thanks Satyan. I've tested the database connection using setnet32 and I'm able to connect to database using squirrel, IBM datastudio, Razor SQL and Server Studio.